# how to download automatically complete genomes with biopython on ncbi

Tags: biopython, ncbi

I'm trying to download automatically all the Klebsiella pneumoniae genomes with biopython. Apparently now there are Size(Mb): 5.68232 Plasmids: 6 Assemblies: 10650. Please I have tried with the function Entrez.esearch. using this link  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/browse#!/prokaryotes/815/